# Similarity Between Basilica Julia Set Structure And Phi-4 Feynman Diagram

Tags: mathematical-physics, fractals

I have found the same vertex-edge graph in two seemingly disparate places and am wondering about any possible connection between the two (beyond just pure coincidence, of course).

The relevant Feynman diagram is one of the quartic $\phi^4$ interactions (one loop, two external legs) found on the Wikipedia page about [Quantum Field Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory#Feynman_diagram):

[image: Feynman Diagram - Phi4]

And the other is in a paper ["Laplacians On The Basilica Julia Set"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3248):

[image: Arc-Type Cell]

where this so-called "arc-type cell" is, roughly speaking, a graph-version of a first-order approximation of the upper boundary of the root basin (basin around $0$) of the "basilica" Julia set of $z_{n+1}=z_n^2-1$, (*red emphasis is mine*):
[image: Basilica Julia Set]

0th and 1st order approximations of basilica set:
[image: 0th and 1st Order Approximations of Basilica Set]

Is this just a structural coincidence? And does this have anything to do with [renormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization)?

Comment: Interesting question to which I have no answer. The common recurrent/recursive nature of these constructions + scaling issues constitute only a first level degree of explanation...

Comment: Somewhat connected: http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~cucuring/Infinitesimal_Resistance_Metrics.pdf

Comment: Have you seen the animation in the answer to this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1150291 ?

Comment: Sorry @JeanMarie! Somehow I wasn't getting notifications on responses! I have not looked at these links but I will now!